# Function querying CosmosDB multiple times

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

We have a Python function (http triggered) trying to fetch data from a CosmosDB(input binding). The amount data being fetched was around 24MB and everything was from 1 partition. This was taking quite a lot time to complete >1min. When we went into Application insights,we found that there were actually multiple (nearly 30-50) queries which were being made to CosmosDB. Even though each of them was completing in millisecond timeframe, the number of queries was adding to the total time taken.[image]
Can anyone help as to why there are multiple queries and is there a way to reduce the number of queries which occur.
I saw some documentation that there is a limit to the size [CosmosDB limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits)and not sure if this is playing a role here but this still doesn't explain that many queries are happening between the function and Cosmos.

Comment: Please share relevant code?

Comment: You haven't shown any queries, but remember that you will be dealing with continuation tokens for larger query return sets. There's a maximum 4MB size of a single response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input binding implementation drains the query of all results: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Bindings/CosmosDBEnumerableBuilder.cs#L39-L46

```
do
{
    DocumentQueryResponse<T> response = await context.Service.ExecuteNextAsync<T>(collectionUri, sqlSpec, continuation);

    finalResults.AddRange(response.Results);
    continuation = response.ResponseContinuation;
}
while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuation));
```

The fact that you are seeing a lot of small executions means your query needs to span multiple roundtrips to complete. It could be the query is cross partitioned, or that the volume of data requires multiple roundtrips (the service has a [4Mb limit on responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits)).

So the number of roundtrips is determined by the query you are executing.

Comment: Thank for this answer. I tried changing the SQL statement from SELECT * to selecting only the fields I needed and I noticed that not only did the RU usage drop but the number of round trips to Cosmos also decreased for heavy queries.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure about Azure Function Python SDK, I think this is **Maximum response size** issue in your query output.
Cosmos DB SDK internally trying to fetch data in batch and return in a single set. To confirm this behaviour, you can try to fetch the same number of records with only 1 or 2 field.

Comment: Thank for this answer. I tried changing the SQL statement from SELECT * to selecting only the fields I needed and I noticed that not only did the RU usage drop but the number of round trips to Cosmos also decreased for heavy queries.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your query is too large (in terms of size **or resource usage**) to process in a single result. The SDK will then make subsequent requests to retrieve the rest of the results using a continuation token. A good indication if the query is the cause would be by opening the browsers developer tools and monitoring the network requests while you fire the query from the Azure Portal.

> Cosmos DB query executions are stateless at the server side, and can be resumed at any time using the x-ms-continuation header. The x-ms-continuation value uses the last processed document resource ID (_rid) to track progress of execution. [[source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api)

You'll likely need to make adjustments to your indexing/partitioning strategy to be more efficient with your queries or increase the RU on your database/container.